# Amazon Web Services: RDS + Web Service vs DynamoDB API for Mobile App. What's Easiest/Best for Security?

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, mobile, amazon-web-services

I'm building a mobile app that needs a backend that I've chosen to host using Amazon Web Services.
Their mobile SDKs provide APIs to work directly with the DynamoDB (making my app a thick client), including user authentication/authorization with their IAM service (which is what I'm going to use to track users). This makes it easy to say "user X wants their information. Here's their temporary access key. Oh, here's the information you requested."

However, if I used RDS as a backend database, I'd have to create web services (in PHP or Java/etc) that my app can talk to. Then I'd also have to implement the authentication/authorization myself within my web service (which I feel could get very messy). I'd also have to host the web service on an EC2 instance, as well as having the RDS instance. So my costs would increase.

The latter seems like it would be a lot of work, something which I could avoid by using DynamoDB (and its API) as my backend.

Am I correct in my reasoning here? Or is there an easy way to authenticate/authorize a PHP web service with an AWS RDS database?
I ask because I've only ever worked with relational databases before, so there would be a learning curve to get the NoSQL db running. Though hypothetically my plan is to eventually switch to a NoSQL db at some point in the future anyways due to my apps increasing demands.

Side note: I already have my database designed in MySQL.

Comment: you make it sound as if NoSQL is by definition superior to RDBMS. This is not always the case. It depends on your app's requirements. Do you ever need joins, etc that are provided by RDBMS? I know that this comment is off topic because you are asking a different question, but are you sure that you will need a NoSQL?

Comment: No, I'm not entirely sure. I'm been doing a ton of reading on NoSQL, but I'm still not sure if it can satisfy all of our needs. FOr instance, I want to be able to provide reports to users based on all the data. I know NoSQL can't do joins, but I honestly don't know how much this limits me because I haven't been able to see a good example of a full NoSQL database "schema" and its uses.

Comment: What did you finally end up using?

Comment: @jasper Sorry mate, we ended up moving towards Azure as the backend before we abandoned the project.

Comment: @G_M Thanks...Wat exactly did u use in Azure as backend and was it any better? Pls also see in case you have any comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242387/mobile-app-backend-service-to-store-retrieve-data

Comment: @jasper Had we kept going with the project we were going to use ASP.NET Web Api and host it in an Azure website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to use IAM directly with RDS because of the unavailability of fine-grained access control over RDS tables. Moreover IAM policies cannot be enforced dynamically  (i.e. with an Identity Pool).
RDS is an unmanaged service, so it is not provided as a SaaS endpoint. DynamoDB is a REST service presented as a distributed key-value store and exposes endpoints to clients (AWS SDK is just a wrapper around them).

DynamoDB is born as a distributed service and can guarantee fine-grained control over data access, thus allowing concurrent access.